# Multiple post types but set the offset only for one

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type, offset

I am displaying multiple post types but i want to set a offset for one of those post type but how can i do that?

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => array('wins', 'memes'),
    'posts_per_page' => '5',
    //'offset' => '1', (with this i set the offset for both but i only want to set it for one of them.)
    'post_status' => 'publish'
);
```

Comment: You can't do it like this. Can you let us know what the purpose of this is (e.g. do you want to exclude the latest post from that type) and we can help come up with a solution that will work :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could gather the IDs that you do not want.  If you don't have a specific order needed from the post type with the offset, and are just looking for the 5 most recents posts from that type. You can do the following:

```
<?php

$posts_to_exclude = array();

$args = array(

  'post_type' => 'wins', // post type you want to offset
  'numberposts' => 5 // the default is 5, but you can add for good measure

);

$posts = get_posts( $args );

if ($posts) {

  foreach ($posts as $post) {

    $posts_to_exclude[] = $post->ID;

  }

}

$args = array(

    'post_type' => array('wins', 'memes'),
    'posts_per_page' => '5',
    'post__not_in' => $posts_to_exclude,
    'post_status' => 'publish'

);

new WP_Query( $args );

// Do more stuff....
```